# Looking for software to convert Audible AA audio files (not AAX) to traditional CDs?

Tags: audio, media-converter, optical-media, audiobook

I recently purchased some audiobooks from Audible.

I chatted with their technical folks twice and both times I was told how to burn Audible audiobooks onto CDs using iTunes. (Excerpts from the chat transcripts are below if you are interested.)

I followed their instructions, which for all intents and purposes were identical, multiple times without success. (It seems futile to call them a third time.)

Can anyone recommend software capable of converting Audible's AA audio files (not AAX) to traditional CDs?

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) and Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)

Budget: Free, if possible, but no more than $45.00

Thanks!

Joe

### First Chat

Ken:  I understand that you wish to burn to CDs. Correct?
Me:   Yes. So I can listen to it in my car (I only have a
      radio/CD player... It was my father's car.)
Ken:  Oh! sorry about that,
Me:   Well, at least I have a car. Some of my friends don't.
Ken:  Well to listen and or burn, you will need to install 
      the Audible software first. Once installed then you may 
      burn to a CD. You need to have iTunes authorized on 
      this account. When you download the Audible Download 
      Manager, make sure you select iTunes.
Me:   Why?
Ken:  To burn a CD, you must iTunes.
Me:   ... and itunes can make a CD so I can listen in my car?
Ken:  Once you install the necessary software 'Audible Download 
      Manager' on your Windows computer. You may access your 
      library and tap to download you book to iTunes. Once 
      downloaded, you may use iTunes to burn to the CD. (More 
      detailed instructions were provided later in the chat.)

### Second Chat

Me:     Do I ever actually own anything?
Henry:  Yes, once you purchase the books they are yours to keep.
Me:     Can I put the audiobook on a CD and listen to it in my 
        car?
Henry:  Yes, you do have an option to burn the audiobooks into 
        several CD's in case you want to listen to them in your 
        car.
Me:     Great! That is exactly what I needed to know. I have my 
        father's old car, the audio system includes AM/FM Radio 
        and CD player, and I am not allowed to wear ear buds 
        when driving.
Henry:  You should have no problem.
Henry:  It was a pleasure. Thank you so much for contacting 
        Audible Chat Support today and I hope you have a great 
        day.  (More detailed instructions were provided later 
        in the chat.)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software* – not dealing with howtos or best approaches. I'd recommend you re-phrase your question so it asks for a software capable of this. Don't forget to include your budget and the OS that software should work on. For a guide, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)